# How to use wildcards in createQueryBuilder?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

In my repository class i use:

```
public function getItemsByTag($tag)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
               ->select('c')
               ->where('c.tags LIKE %bipolar%')
               ->addOrderBy('c.id');

    return $qb->getQuery()
              ->getResult();
}
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work.. Anybody knows how this can work? Or do I have to build a custom query without the QueryBuilder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to substitute your query with variables but use a static string you have to put the string in apostrophes.

You **have** to use apostrophes instead of quotes! Otherwise the Doctrine2 Lexer will throw an Exception.

So in your case Mike you can use:

```
'c.tags LIKE \'%bipolar%\''
```

or

```
"c.tags like '%bipolar%'"
```

Answer (score 13):

**Searching based on a single parameter:**

I think it should go:

```
public function getItemsByTag($tag)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
           ->select('c')
           ->where('c.tags LIKE :tag')
           ->addOrderBy('c.id')
           ->setParameter('tag', $tag);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

But I think that it is discouraged to do a LIKE as part of a where using the query builder so you should do:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');

$qb->select('c')
   ->where($qb->expr()->like('c.tags', '?1'))
   ->addOrderBy('c.id')
   ->setParameter(1, $tag);

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Check out the docs for more information, there is an example of a like expression in the section entitled [Helper Methods](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/query-builder.html#helper-methods)

I should also point out that I used a different convention in each example for passing a parameter into a query, the first used a named parameter `:tag` which is set by `setParameter('tag', $value)` the second is just a numbered parameter `?1`, you could have just as easily have used a named parameter in the second example if you wished to as well.

**Searching with an array of parameters:**

You also asked about doing an array of likes. Here it is with an OR expression but if you wanted to search for all tags you could change it to an AND.

In order to make a "LIKE array" you just have to build up the expression on its own.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');

$orExpr = $qb->expr()->orX();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($tags); $i++) {
    $orExpr->add($qb->expr->like('c.tags', "?$i"));

    // You may have to set params later in a loop after $orExpr has been
    // added to the queryBuilder.
    $qb->setParameter($i, $tags[$i]);
}

$qb->select('c')->where($orExpr)->addOrderBy('c.id');

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Kasheen, do you know if I can do that even with an array of tags?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm supposed to answer a second question but since it is related I'll modify my answer to include what I *think* should work. :)

Comment: Hi Kasheen, this actually throws an exception. Obviously $likeExprs  needs to be an object and it comes as array... (Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given in .../vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr/Base.php line 61). If I add add the Expr. Manually (->where($qb->expr()->orX(
$qb->expr()->like('c.tags', "?0"), $qb->expr()->like('c.tags', "?1"))) it works fine. But that's not what I wanted to accomplish :-( I am really feeling lost right now, do you have an answer? Many Thanks though, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: The API for `$qb->expr()->orX()` expects multiple parameters, I was mistaken that an array could be automatically converted into multiple parameters so I'll update my answer once again but after this I think you may need to open it as a new question if it doesn't work out - you might get help faster if the question is specifically worded to the arrays problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Symfony, but based on what I know about PHP and MySQL, I imagine you mean `'c.tags LIKE "%bipolar%"'`.  You likely need quotation marks around `%bipolar%`.

Answer (score 0):

simply:

```
public function getItemsByTag($tag)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
           ->select('c')
           ->where( $qb->expr()->like('c.tags', ':tags') )
           ->addOrderBy('c.id');

    $qb->setParameter('tags', '%' . $tag . '%' );

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```